# Dominio en Godaddy dirigido a Google Sites

Tags: dns, dominio, godaddy, google-sites

tengo el dominio en godaddy y la pagina la hice con google sites, el dominio me funciona bien cuando lo escribo [www.contalife.com](http://www.contalife.com) pero cuando escribo en el navegador contalife.com (sin la www) me da error
404. Eso es un error.
Google
No se encontró la dirección URL solicitada en este servidor. Eso es todo lo que sabemos./, yo agregue los registros A de google a mi dns

@   3600    A   216.239.32.21

@   3600    A   216.239.34.21

@   3600    A   216.239.36.21

@   3600    A   216.239.38.21

pero no me funcionaron, los quite todos y tampoco me funciono, sigue saliendo el error. espere la 72 horas y seguia igual, por favor si me pueden ayudar con la configuracion del dns para que me funcione el dominio simple contalife.com

Saludos